# Visual studio debugging with sudo rights

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use keyboard python module in my python code, so I need to run code with sudo through terminal. But I also need to debug through visual studio, but then I can't use keyboard module.

Comment: Could you give more details? What are your expectations. Maybe pictures can help us understand better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just needed to add sudo to configuration in launch.json...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).